Необходимо написать запрос JQL для структуры в JIRA, чтобы вывести в структуре заявки и связанные с ними задачи/заявки
Нужна помощь в написании запроса (не смог победить, сдаюсь) следующего характера:
Есть проект А. В нем создаются сервисные запросы. Есть проекты Б, В, Г и Д - в них создают задачи и сервисные запросы, связанные с сервисными запросами проекта А.
Какой запрос нужно написать, чтобы вывести в структуре иерархии сервисных запросов проекта А и все связанные сервисные запросы и заявки из других проектов? Запрос проекта А и ниже все связанные запросы и задач из других проектов.  и так по каждому из запросов проекта А.
Понимаю, что через linkedissues, но не могу придумать, как.
Заранее спасибо!
Пробовал issue in linkedissue, но не получилось.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
